# How do I serve a static page as the default action of a MVC application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC application and a static page (that happens to be called `index.html`) in the root directory.

I am trying to figure out a way to serve this static page when the website is first loaded i.e. the default action should be that a visitor to my site is presented with the static page.

How can I do this in my application?

Comment: index view of default controller?

Comment: that's not how asp.net mvc works. You should create a controller and an action in the controller and view for that action.

Comment: Model View Controller

Comment: -1 for lack of research. You clearly have absolutely no idea how the basics of ASP.NET MVC work. Read some tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Well those of you who think I have no idea than I say you have no idea about MVC. You need to stop following the crowd and think out of box to make elegant solutions. Here I found out how to do it ....public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File("index.html", "text/html");
}

Comment: @J.Davidson If you figured out a solution you are encouraged to answer your own question and you can even accept your own answer after a day or so

Comment: @RobV where is the option to answer my own question? Thanks

Comment: It is currently unavailable because your question got put on hold, if the question gets reopened then you could post your own answer

Comment: @J.Davidson I have attempted to rewrite the question to make it more general and hopefully avoid the knee jerk reactions that appear to have got this put on hold.  Note I am not that familiar with ASP.Net MVC so if I've got the terminology slightly wrong in my rewrite please go ahead and correct it appropriately. I have also nominated the question for reopening which it will hopefully get approved for

Answer (score 2):

Check for RouteConfig.cs file in App_Start folder and change the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

and it should be index.cshtml not index.html.
Change your controller attribute accordingly.

You also need to add the following code to your controller,

```
public actionresult Index()
{ 
    return View();
}
```

Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a home controller in place and you understand the

### HomeController

```
Public ActionResult Index() 
{
    return View(); //or you can choose to do this: return View("~/Index.cshtml") <- specifying the document path explicitly 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's set in your `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "CIS.PresentationLayer.Controllers" }
        );
```

This route will start the Index view of the LoginCOntroller when the MVC application is run.

Also note that you will need a Controller, for example

```
 public class LoginController : Controller
 {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel() { Authenticated = true } );
    }
 }
```